# Filtros Data URL CSV Python

Tags: python, csv

Estoy trabajando con un reporte que obtengo desde una URL. Estoy buscando hacer filtros los cuales me retornen solo los datos de la columna Fillrate menores a 0.05 junto con los datos de name,request,impressions y una vez obtenido solo esos valores guardarlos en un CSV. No se como hacer ese tipo de operaciones. Python 2.7

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookieliz

#Usuario y contraseña
username = 'email'
password = 'contraseña'


#Cookies
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
#Equivale a un POST
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'username' : username, 'password' : password})
opener.open('https://ppp.com/login', login_data)

#Reportes
resp = opener.open('https://ppp.com/reports/csv/11777')
content = resp.read()
print content
```

aca termina el codigo. Lo que obtengo es lo siguiente:

```
"Inventory Name","Requests","Impressions","Fill Rate"
"aaass MWasdS","569737093","244066","0.04"
"bssss","331270265","381168","0.12"
"cumbia","152492369","190008","0.12"
"cuadrupedia","133983625","53184","0.04"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas.read_csv` puede leer de una dirección http\https un csv de forma directa. El problema es que requieres autentificarte y el uso de cookies, en este caso solo puedes hacer algo como lo que haces y cargar el DataFrame una vez obtenidos los datos con `urllib`, `request` o cualquier otra librería especializada.

Puedes usar [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#StringIO.StringIO) que permite leer y escribir en buffers de string,  pudiendo tratar el string `content` como si fuera un archivo y usar `pandas.read_csv` como harías normalmente:

```
import urllib
import urllib2 
from StringIO import StringIO
import cookieliz

#Usuario y contraseña
username = 'email'
password = 'contraseña'


#Cookies
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
#Equivale a un POST
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'username' : username, 'password' : password})
opener.open('https://ppp.com/login', login_data)

#Reportes
resp = opener.open('https://ppp.com/reports/csv/11777')
content = resp.read()
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(content))
```

También puedes guardar en tu disco duro el csv en un archivo y cargarlo normalmente con pandas.

```
with open("datos.csv", "wb") as f:
    f.write(content)

df = pd.read_csv("datos.csv")
```

Una vez que tienes el DataFrame cargado de cualquiera de las dos formas, el resto es simple:

```
df = df[df['Fill Rate'] < 0.05]
df.to_csv("salida.csv", sep=',')
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! Me solucionaste el problema! Saludos

Comment: sabes como puedo evitar que me muestre el numero de filas que automaticamente me muestra en salida.csv con df.to_csv??

Comment: @MartinBouhier ¿Te refieres a omitir  la primera columna?, ¿los indices por defecto de las filas del dataframe?

Comment: @MartinBouhier si no recuerdo mal y lo que quieres es eliminar la columna de indices  era pasando el parametro `index=False` , seria asi `df.to_csv("salida.csv", sep=',', index=False)`

Comment: Eso necesitaba el index! Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Martín, independientemente de la respuesta de @FJSevilla que es la apropiada en tu caso ya que usas pandas, solo a modo informativo, una solución mediante "python" puro pasa por el uso de la comprensión de listas:

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookieliz

#Usuario y contraseña
username = 'email'
password = 'contraseña'

#Cookies
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
#Equivale a un POST
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'username' : username, 'password' : password})
opener.open('https://ppp.com/login', login_data)

#Reportes
resp = opener.open('https://ppp.com/reports/csv/11777')
content = resp.read()

# Creamos una lista separando por \n y luego por , y quitamos las comillas de cada campo
datos = [[w.replace('"', '') for w in e] for e in [l.split(",") for l in content.split("\n")] if len(e) == 4]

# Filtramos los datos quitando los encabezados 
datos_filtrados =  [c for c in [fila for fila in datos[1:]] if float(c[3]) <= 0.05]

print(datos_filtrados)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la Info Patricio! Un abrazo